# Double select from a same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table categories that looks like this. My categories can span up to 4 levels deep but I have chosen to always show only one level bellow the selected one.

```
| id | parent_id | name | ... |
| 1  |    0      |  A   | ... |
| 2  |    1      |  A1  | ... |
| 3  |    2      |  A2  | ... |
| 4  |    1      |  A3  | ... |
| 5  |    0      |  B   | ... |
```

Basically I'm trying to select parent categories and their first level children. So after select I should get all rows where `parent_id = 0` and where `parent_id = parent_id` from the parents.

I should get:

```
| id | parent_id | name | ... |
| 1  |     0     |  A   | ... |
| 2  |     1     |  A1  | ... |
| 4  |     1     |  A2  | ... |
| 5  |     0     |  B   | ... |
```

I tried:

```
SELECT * AS t1 FROM categories
    WHERE parent_id = 0 AND WHERE parent_id = t1.id;
```

I'm very new to SQL with code I could do this easy with PHP but I don't want to select everything and then do a complex sort function.

How can I select the table once to select `parent_id` and then do a second select into this select I just did where parent_id's from categories table equal id's in the select I just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT  *
FROM    categories
WHERE   parent_id = 0 
UNION ALL
SELECT  c.* 
FROM    categories c INNER JOIN
        categories p    ON  c.parent_id = p.id
WHERE   p.parent_id = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use self join to achieve the same,

```
SELECT *  FROM categories c1,
               categories c2 
          WHERE c1.parent_id = 0 
          AND c1.parent_id = c2.id
```

Comment: I tried similar to this, but didn't work. Yours throws a SQL error: WHERE c1.parent_id = c2.id on this line.